# Asynchronous finding highest number

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

im looking for a way to asynchronous iterate over an array and update a variable and in the end return this variable.

```
export const test = async(
...
): Promise<number> => {
let highestAmount = 0;
    for (const entry of entries) {
        const check = async () => {
            let amount = 0
            try {
                newAmount = await getAmount(entry);
            } catch (e) {
                return;
            }
            if (newAmount > amount ) {
                highestAmount = newAmount;
           }
        }
        check()
    }
    return highestAmount;
}
```

In this current state i only get 0's back because the function doesnt wait for its finish.
Is there a way that the function only returns if all processes inside the for are finished ?
Lets say the `getAmount(entry)` function takes 1 second to finish then i have to wait around `entries.length` seconds. Im trying to find a way to execute this in 1 second so `getAmount` is called for every entry asynchronously => function returns highest number

Comment: The `async` keyword does not make a function asynchronous.

Comment: What does `getAmount` do? Is it a fetch to an API?

Comment: yes getAmount is a fetch to an API, @Pointy im relatively new to ts and js :) so you recommend another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lets say the `getAmount(entry)` function takes 1 second to finish then i have to wait around `entries.length` seconds. I'm trying to find a way to execute this in 1 second

If you have five calls that take one second you can't execute and return a value from the function in one second.

> Is there a way that the function only returns if all processes inside the for are finished?

Yes. This, however, is possible.

If you [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your array to produce an array of promises that you can `await` with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you can then use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to get the highest number from that array.

```js
// Generate a random number
function rnd() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 0) + 0);
}

// Mock API call which returns the number passed into
// multiplied by an erratic method of
// creating a new random number
function getAmount(el) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res((el - rnd()) + rnd()), 500);
  });
}

// Create an array of promises, await them to resolve
// and then return the highest number
async function getHighest(entries) {
  const promises = entries.map(el => getAmount(el));
  const data = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(data);
  return Math.max(...data);
}

// Await the promise that `getData` returns
// and log the result
async function main(entries) {
  console.log(await getHighest(entries));
}

const entries = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

main(entries);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things missing to make this wait:

1. Put an async in the parent function
2. Put an await in the check function call

For example:

```js
export const test = async (
...
): Promise<number> => {
  //...
  await check();
};
```

There might also be ways to make these async calls run in parallel.